# How can I improve this code? I don't like to put so many ifs

Tags: c, arduino

I have the following code, but I feel dirty..

I don't like to write so many ifs and then put repeated code in each if..

Any ideas on how can I improve this  code?

```
char obj[5];
strlcpy(obj, &jarr[i], arr[i]);
if( !strcmp( obj, "led_r" ) ){
    i++;
    strlcpy( obj, &jarr[i], arr[i] );
    red_brightness = atoi( obj );

    Serial.print(" RED: ");
    Serial.println( red_brightness );
}
if( !strcmp( obj, "led_g" ) ){
    i++;
    strlcpy( obj, &jarr[i], arr[i] );
    green_brightness = atoi( obj );

    Serial.print(" GREEN: ");
    Serial.println( green_brightness );
}
if( !strcmp( obj, "led_b" ) ){
    i++;
    strlcpy( obj, &jarr[i], arr[i] );
    blue_brightness = atoi( obj );

    Serial.print(" BLUE: ");
    Serial.println( blue_brightness );
}
```

Comment: You could put it in a for loop

Comment: @toddlermenot but (s)he wants to do all of the ifs that return true, not just one.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh: my bad. didn't notice the `strlcpy` which modifies `obj`.

Comment: `char obj[5];` --> `char obj[6];`

Comment: I would make each of those if code blocks into a separate function.  Then the code inside the if statements would be nothing but a call to the appropriate function

Comment: can you give information about what are jarr and arr ? i wonder about the &jarr[i] ... ( why not jarr[i] ). and char obj[5] should be bigger, first because it hold an final '\0' and second because your brightness value is an integer and can be more than 6 chars ...

Answer (score 5):

The other answers prior to this are good too.  The advantage of this answer is that you can change the option names to anything and it would still work.  You can also extend this kind of option parsing to a much larger set of options.

```
// Assuming these are globals.
int red_brightness, green_brightness, blue_brightness;

// Use this array to help you parse.
static const struct {
    const char *optionName;
    int        *brightness;
    const char *label;
} ledOptions[] = {
    { "led_r", &red_brightness,   " RED: "   },
    { "led_g", &green_brightness, " GREEN: " },
    { "led_b", &blue_brightness,  " BLUE: "  },
};

// A handy macro for later.
#define DIM(array)  (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

...

// Now in your actual code:    
strlcpy(obj, &jarr[i], arr[i]);
for (j=0;j<DIM(ledOptions);j++) {
    if( !strcmp( obj, ledOptions[i].optionName ) ){
        i++;
        strlcpy( obj, &jarr[i], arr[i] );
        *ledOptions[i].brightness = atoi( obj );

        Serial.print(ledOptions[i].label);
        Serial.println(*ledOptions[i].brightness);
    }
}
```

Comment: impressive answer given short delay... i was writing quite the same thing.

Comment: Nice answer. (3 char).

Answer (score 2):

Compare the first 4 characters with "led_", make sure it has length 5, and then switch on the fifth character. Refactor the rest of the code into a function.

Answer (score 2):

The common code can be factored out of the if statement

You can use a switch statement for the only character that changes in the string

```
switch(obj[4]) {
    case 'r':
        Serial.println("RED: " + red_brightness );
    case 'g':
        Serial.println("GREEN: " + green_brightness );
    case 'b':
        Serial.println("BLUE: " + blue_brightness );
}
```

Comment: Except without using `const char *` as the cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Disclaimer, I haven't tried to compile/run it.

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
   i++;
   int b = atoi( &jarr[i] );
   switch (i)
   {
     case 1:
        Serial.print(" RED: ");
        red_brightness = b;
        break;
     case 3: 
        Serial.print(" GREEN: ");
        green_brightness = b;
        break;
     case 5:
        Serial.print(" BLUE: ");
        blue_brightness = b;
        break;
     default:
        break;
   }
   Serial.println(b);
}
```

The idea being that values you want to print are in the &jarr[] at the odd number indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here my personal approach of this ...

```
#ifndef ARDUINO
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* PART of code derived from question but unspecified in code . done to be able to compile */

// this is not specified in question 
//   either it a char jarr[1024] but then why do we iterate on char ( i++ would go to next char and not to next word )
//   either it is a char* jar[6] but then we access its char * content with jarr[i] and not with &jarr[i]
//char * jarr[6];
// this look like to be size of each argument.
//int arr[6];

/*
TEST vectors
 */

char * jarr0[] = { "led_r", "200", "led_g", "100", "led_b", "150" };
int arr0[] = { 5, 3, 5,3, 5,3 };

char * jarr1[] = { "led_g", "200", "led_r", "100", "led_b", "150" };
int arr1[] = { 5, 3, 5,3, 5,3 };

char * jarr2[] = { "lgd_g", "200", "ged_r", "100", "led_b", "150" };
int arr2[] = { 5, 3, 5,3, 5,3 };

int red_brightness = 0;
int blue_brightness = 0;
int green_brightness = 0;

/* end of unspecified PART */
#endif

/*real code *

/* use indirection */
struct led_color_map {
  int * color_brightness_p;
  const char * color_name;
  char key;
} led_color[] = {
  {&red_brightness,"RED",'r'},
  {&green_brightness,"GREEN",'g'},
  {&blue_brightness,"BLUE",'b'}
};


enum { RED_IDX=0, GREEN_IDX, BLUE_IDX };

// for perf test
int miss = 0;

#ifdef ARDUINO
void led_setup()
#else
  void led_setup(char * jarr[], int arr[])
#endif
{

  char* obj=NULL;
  int i=0;
  int offset=0;

  for (i=0; i <6; i+=2)
    {
      obj=jarr[i];
      // test 'led_' prefix with reverse statistical letter apparence
      // which is 'l' then 'd' then 'e' , guessing that '_' can be used in other words ... 
      if ( ( obj[0] == 'l' ) && ( obj[2] == 'd' ) && (obj[1] == 'e' ) && (obj[3] == '_') )
    {
      int idx=0;
      for ( idx = 0; idx <= BLUE_IDX; idx ++)
        {
          int rolling_idx = (idx + offset) % ( BLUE_IDX + 1 );
          struct led_color_map * color_found = &led_color[rolling_idx]; 
          if ( color_found->key == obj[4] )
        {
          char ivalue[32];
          if ( arr[i+1] < sizeof(ivalue) )
            {
              #ifdef ARDUINO
              strlcpy(ivalue, jarr[i+1], arr[i+1]);
              #else
              strncpy(ivalue, jarr[i+1], arr[i+1]);
              #endif
              {
            int brightness = atoi( ivalue );
            *(color_found->color_brightness_p) = brightness;
            #ifdef ARDUINO
            Serial.print( color_found->color_name );
            Serial.println( *color_brightness );
            #else
            printf(" %s :%i\n", color_found->color_name, brightness);
            #endif
              }
              offset=(rolling_idx + 1) % ( BLUE_IDX + 1 ); // try with next color first next time.
              break;
            }
        }
          else
        {
          miss ++;
          printf("miss %i wrong color order expected %s\n",miss, led_color[rolling_idx].color_name);
        }
        }     
    }
      else
    {
      miss ++;
      printf("miss %i wrong variable expected led_%c\n", miss, led_color[offset % ( BLUE_IDX + 1 )].key);
    }
    }

}

#ifndef ARDUINO
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

led_setup(jarr0, arr0);
 printf("test0 : miss %i\n",miss);

miss=0;
led_setup(jarr1, arr1);
 printf("test1 : miss %i\n",miss);

miss=0;
led_setup(jarr2, arr2);
 printf("test2 : miss %i\n",miss);

}
#endif
```

gcc led.c
./a.out

```
 RED :200
 GREEN :100
 BLUE :150
test0 : miss 0
miss 1 wrong color order expected RED
 GREEN :200
miss 2 wrong color order expected BLUE
 RED :100
miss 3 wrong color order expected GREEN
 BLUE :150
test1 : miss 3
miss 1 wrong variable expected led_r
miss 2 wrong variable expected led_r
miss 3 wrong color order expected RED
miss 4 wrong color order expected GREEN
 BLUE :150
test2 : miss 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char obj[5];
strlcpy(obj, &jarr[i], arr[i]);
int *brightness;
String ostr();
if( !strcmp( obj, "led_r" ) ){
 ostr = " RED: ";
 brightness = red_brightness;
}
if( !strcmp( obj, "led_g" ) ){
 ostr = " GREEN: ";
 brightness = green_brightness;
}
if( !strcmp( obj, "led_b" ) ){
 ostr = " BLUE: ";
 brightness = blue_brightness;
}
i++;
strlcpy( obj, &jarr[i], arr[i] );
*brightness = atoi( obj );
Serial.print(ostr);
Serial.println(*brightness);
```